# Adding padding between form elements

Tags: html, css

I am looking to add padding between elements of my form, as currently they are tight together. How can I adjust my css? Nothing has seemed to work thus far.

I would like the forgotten password the same proportional distance away from the button, but the button and form fields need more space between them.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:400,500,600,700,800,900');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding {
  background: #f0f0f0 !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  padding-left: 20vw;
  min-width: 100%;
}


h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,


label,
span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'inter';
}

body,
html,
.App,
#root,
.auth-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p{
  font-family: Inter;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 28px;
color: #939599;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #494D61;
  
  }

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.Logo {
  padding-top: 2vh;
}

.auth-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  background:#ffffff;
  padding: 8vw 0;
  position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.auth-inner {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}


.auth-wrapper .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #FBB381;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.auth-wrapper .form-control {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
border-color: #EBEBEB;

}

.auth-wrapper h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #FBB381;
}




.form-signup {
  display: grid; /* to use css-grid */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* creates 2 columns */
  gap: 10px 50px; /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
  
}

.form-login {
  display: flex; /* to use css-grid */
  width: 35vw;
  gap: 10px 50px; /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
 
}


form h3,
form h4,
form p,
form button {
  grid-column: span 2; /* lets those elements span both columns */
}

.signup-button {
  grid-column: span 2; /* lets those elements span both columns */
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white
}


.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 75vw;
  /* flexbox is sued to palce the label and input below each other and allows the input to fill out the entrie width */
}


.button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;

}

.login-button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.sidebar-container{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.sidebar {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.sidebar-link{
  padding: 0px;
}

.sidebar-link:hover{
  border-right: 5px solid #FBB381;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<div className="auth-wrapper">
            <div className="auth-inner">
            <form className="form-login">

                <div className="login">
                <h4>Sign In</h4>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
                    
                </div>
              
           
                <button type="submit" className="button">Login</button>
                <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                    Forgot <a href="/">password?</a>
                </p>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: There's a huge amount of surplus CSS in your posted demo, as well as the `className` attribute in your HTML (which should be `class`), I'm assuming you're using React (or similar), but could you trim your code down to the [mcve] code necessary to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```css
form.form-login .login > div.form-group {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

This gives top and bottom margins to all `.form-group` divs nested in `form-login` and `login`.

Comment: @KirkCode see edits - that should work just fine.

Comment: Oops. Retroactively confirmed answer. My bad

Answer (score 1):

For (vertical) distance *between* elements don't use `padding`, but `margin`, i.e. `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

You want ***margin*** not ***padding***. Margin will take the margin area, bounded by the margin edge, extending the border area to include an empty area used to separate the element from its neighbors. Padding, bounded by the padding edge, extends the content area to include the element's padding.

You can tell CSS to add margin to all but the first element of its type, this will ensure you don't get unwanted margin on the first element and only on the preceding elements. `:not(:nth-of-type(1))` => ***not the first element***

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:400,500,600,700,800,900');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding {
  background: #f0f0f0 !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  padding-left: 20vw;
  min-width: 100%;
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
label,
span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'inter';
}

body,
html,
.App,
#root,
.auth-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #939599;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #494D61;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.Logo {
  padding-top: 2vh;
}

.auth-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 8vw 0;
  position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.auth-inner {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.auth-wrapper .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #FBB381;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.auth-wrapper .form-control {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-color: #EBEBEB;
}

.auth-wrapper h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #FBB381;
}

.form-signup {
  display: grid;
  /* to use css-grid */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* creates 2 columns */
  gap: 10px 50px;
  /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
}

.form-login {
  display: flex;
  /* to use css-grid */
  width: 35vw;
  gap: 10px 50px;
  /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
}

form h3,
form h4,
form p,
form button {
  grid-column: span 2;
  /* lets those elements span both columns */
}

.signup-button {
  grid-column: span 2;
  /* lets those elements span both columns */
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 75vw;
  /* flexbox is sued to palce the label and input below each other and allows the input to fill out the entrie width */
}

.form-group:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.login-button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidebar-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.sidebar {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.sidebar-link {
  padding: 0px;
}

.sidebar-link:hover {
  border-right: 5px solid #FBB381;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth-wrapper">
  <div class="auth-inner">
    <form class="form-login">
      <div class="login">
        <h4>Sign In</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Login</button>
        <p class="forgot-password text-right">
          Forgot <a href="/">password?</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```